# Compute Normalized Score with Google Sheet Formula

Tags: python, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
        Score1    Score2    Score3
Joe          8         5         3 
Jane         4         6         2
Abdul        5         5         3
Nadia        9         7         5
```

I want to compute a new column containing an "average normalized score" (ANS) for each person, where for each score I get a "normalized score" by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation over that score-column, and then average up those normalized scores to get the ANS per-person.

The result should be:

```
        Score1    Score2    Score3        ANS
Joe          8         5         3     -0.135
Jane         4         6         2     -0.686
Abdul        5         5         3     -0.621
Nadia        9         7         5      1.44
```

The python-esque pseudo-code for this operation would be:

```
for j in [1..N_cols]:
    mean_scores = mean(score[i, j] for i in [1..N_rows])
    std_scores = std(score[i, j] for i in [1..N_rows])
    for i in [1..N_rows]:
        norm_scores[i, j] = (scores[i, j] - mean_scores)/std_scores

for i in [1..N_rows]:
    avg_norm_scores[i] = mean(norm_scores[i, j] for j in [1..N_cols])
```

Or in numpy it would simply be:

`avg_norm_scores = ((scores - scores.mean(axis=0))/scores.std(axis=0)).mean(axis=1)`

What is the most succinct way I could calculate a new column containing the ANS in google sheets?

Comment: can you include math equation of getting ANS?

Comment: http://latex2png.com/output//latex_2e58e0e072f4f10cdabb83f92d0396c7.png

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most succinct, but the right answers:

```
=average((B2-average(B:B))/STDEVP(B:B),(C2-average(C:C))/STDEVP(C:C),(D2-average(D:D))/STDEVP(D:D))
```

copied down to suit, assuming `8` is in B2.

Comment: Thanks, yes I ended up doing this.  Was hoping there'd be some way to loop over columns because I have 8 in my real example and the equation gets messy